# Update table in MySQL by csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I must update table `cscart_products` by `csv` file `output.csv`.

I have created a temporary table (`your_temp_table`) and with command `INNER JOIN` updated `cscart_products` table (`product_code`, `amount`).

When executing the following code, MySQL report this error:

> The user update failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE cscart_products INNER JOIN your_temp_table on your_temp_table.amount = cs' at line 6

Is there an error? Is the SQL syntax wrong?

```
<?php
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'output.csv'
       INTO TABLE your_temp_table
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    (product_code, amount);

UPDATE cscart_products
INNER JOIN your_temp_table on your_temp_table.amount = cscart_products.amount
SET cscart_products.product_code = your_temp_table.product_code;";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxxx","xxxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
};

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) {
  $message = "The data was successfully added!";
} else {
  $message = "The user update failed: ";
  $message .= mysqli_error($con); 
};

echo $message;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in mysqli they should be executed as two queries

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'output.csv'
       INTO TABLE your_temp_table
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    (product_code, amount)";

$sql2 = "UPDATE cscart_products
INNER JOIN your_temp_table on your_temp_table.amount = cscart_products.amount
SET cscart_products.product_code = your_temp_table.product_code";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
```

Or, you have to use [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)